# How to make Mathematica re-evaluate a cell after some event?

Tags: evaluation

I am doing a little project to demonstrate something:

```
a = 2; b = 5000; 
d = 10000; l1 = {};  
rc := RandomChoice[{a, b} -> {0, 1}]
c = 1; While[c <= d, AppendTo[l1, rc];c++] 
e = ((Count[l1, _] - Count[l1, 0])/d)*100//N 
f = 100 - e
```

I want to insert two InputFields for the values of A and B, but I want it to re-evaluate the rest of the cell whenever I input new values for A and B - I'm also curious for A or B.

**Note** - Inserting the inputfields is not my problem, my problems is only the reevaluation of the cell after some event.

Comment: Are you looking for Dynamic?

Comment: @Szalbocs Kinda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution IMHO is using `Manipulate`. Almost no change in your code is necessary:

```
Manipulate[
 d = 10000; l1 = {};
 rc := RandomChoice[{a, b} -> {0, 1}];
 c = 1; While[c <= d, AppendTo[l1, rc]; c++];
 Column[
  {
   e = ((Count[l1, _] - Count[l1, 0])/d)*100 // N,
   f = 100 - e
   }
  ],
 {a, 2}, {b, 5000},
 TrackedSymbols -> {a, b}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is indeed the simplest! I think I have to relearn `Manipulate` before overcomplicating things.

Comment: @IstvánZachar, so do I. It is an area of Mathematica I am not familiar with.

Comment: Nice, didn't know i could apply `Manipulate` that way.

Comment: @Sjoerd There's a problem here: It keeps evaluating _ad infinitum_, I want it to evaluate only when the values of **a** or **b** are changed.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Did you include the `TrackedSymbols -> {a, b}` line specifically entered here to prevent that and are your a and b in lowercase (and not uppercase as in the text of your question)?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira another possibility is that you have more Manipulates open with the same variables. Since I haven't localized the symbols using `DynamicModule` the others may influence this one.

Comment: @Sjoerd I just pasted your code, but mine was open for some time, I guess this was the problem, I re-opened Mathematica and pasted it again, now it works.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, doesn't Manipulate add a dynamicModule to localize by default?

Comment: @Rojo True, but that wasn't what I intended to address. Try executing two  instances of the following for instance: `Manipulate[
 a = test2;
 test = a, {test, 1, 10}, {test2, 1, 10}]`

Comment: I see, interesting

Answer (score 8):

Using `DynamicModule` (note that I modified some of your default values to give a more intuitive output):

```
   DynamicModule[{a = 2, b = 5, d = 30, update, e, f, temp = 1, rc, l1},

 Grid[{
   {"weight of 0 (a)", InputField[Dynamic[a, (a = #; update[]) &]]},
   {"weight of 1 (b)", InputField[Dynamic[b, (b = #; update[]) &]]},
   {"random choice from (0, 1) (rc)", Dynamic@rc},
   {"list (l1)", Dynamic@l1},
   {"e", Dynamic@e},
   {"f", Dynamic@f}
   }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}],

 Initialization :> (
   update[] := Module[{c = 1},
     l1 = {};
     rc = RandomChoice[{a, b} -> {0, 1}];
     While[c <= d, AppendTo[l1, rc]; c++];
     e = ((Count[l1, _] - Count[l1, 0])/d)*100 // N;
     f = 100 - e;
     temp++;
     ];
   update[]
   )]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your method is also nice. It has some functions i've never seen. I'll explore them too.